# Django: The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, httpresponse

I keep getting this error when I try to use my 'edit' url.

The view to_do_list_app.views.edit didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

my url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.todo, name='todo'),
    path('delete/<job_id>', views.delete, name='delete'),
    path('cross_off/<job_id>', views.cross_off, name='cross_off'),
    path('uncross/<job_id>', views.uncross, name='uncross'),
    path('edit/<job_id>', views.edit, name='edit'),
]
```

from django.db import models.py

```
class Jobs(models.Model):
    # Relationships
    to_do_owner = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    # Fields
    item = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item +' | ' +  str(self.completed)
```

Here is my veiws.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Jobs
from .forms import ListForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def edit(request, job_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item = Jobs.objects.get(pk=job_id)
        form = ListForm(request.POST or None, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid() and request.POST['item'] != '':
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, request.POST['item']+ ' er blevet redigeret i din opgave list')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('todo')
    else:
        item =Jobs.objects.get(pk=job_id)
        context = {'item': item}
        return render(request, 'edit.html', context)
```

And here I have my template edith.html

```
<form class="d-flex" method="POST" action="{% url 'edit' item.id %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="{{  item.item  }}"
               value="{{  item.item  }}" aria-label="Search" name="item">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{  user.username  }}" name="job_owner">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{  item.completed  }}" name="completed">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Rediger opgave</button>
    </form>
```

The output for self.check_response(response, callback)  is:

> callback
> <function edit at 0x7f07ac82b430>
> callback_args
> ()
> callback_kwargs
> {'job_id': '5'}
> middleware_method
> <bound method CsrfViewMiddleware.process_view of <django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware object at 0x7f07ac89b760>>
> request
> <WSGIRequest: POST '/todo/edit/5'>
> response
> None
> self
> <django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler object at 0x7f07adbea760>
> wrapped_callback
> <function edit at 0x7f07ac82b430>

Comment: If it is a POST request, and the form is ***not*** valid, you do not return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like :-

```
def edit(request, job_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item = Jobs.objects.get(pk=job_id)
        form = ListForm(request.POST or None, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid() and request.POST['item'] != '':
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, request.POST['item']+ ' er blevet redigeret i din opgave list')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('todo')
    else:
        item =Jobs.objects.get(pk=job_id)

    context = {'item': item}
    return render(request, 'edit.html', context)
```

**What i have edited :-** Indentation of last two lines

Comment: I'm having this problem on Class Based UpdateView, when I'm using `def post(self, request, **kwargs):` to update a model.